# Какая разница между width:auto и width:fit-content?

Tags: html, css

Пример с `width: auto`

```css
.block {
  width: 300px;
  width: auto;
  height: min-content;
  background: yellowgreen;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.parent {
  background: yellowgreen;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="block">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
</div>
```

Пример с `width: fit-content`

```css
.block {
  width: 300px;
  width: fit-content;
  height: min-content;
  background: yellowgreen;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.parent {
  background: yellowgreen;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="block">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
</div>
```

Как видно, ведут эти два свойства себя совершенно одинаково

P.S. Также не совсем понятна формула свойства fit-content – min(maximum size, max(minimum size, argument)). Что из себя представляет в данном случае "аргумент"?
[Формула](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content)

Comment: Ту ссылку, которую вы приложили, там это для гридов, но не для свойства width или height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Источник](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/width)
**`fit-content`**
Наибольшее из

1. внутренней минимальной ширины
2. меньшей из внутренней предпочтительной ширины и доступной ширины

```css
.fit-content {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 0;
  min-width: 400px;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="fit-content">
  fit-content
</div>
```

Если вы хотели это для гридов использовать:

```css
grid-template-columns: fit-content(300px) fit-content(300px) 1fr;
```

Первый и второй элемент в ряду будут занимать максимум 300px в ширину

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: fit-content(300px) fit-content(300px) 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #8cffa0;
  padding: 10px;
}

#container>div {
  background-color: #8ca0ff;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    Элемент с дополнительным текстом. Поскольку его содержимое превышает максимальную ширину, оно ограничено 300 пикселей.
  </div>
  <div>
    Элемент с дополнительным текстом. Поскольку его содержимое превышает максимальную ширину, оно ограничено 300 пикселей.
  </div>
  <div>Флексовый элемент</div>
</div>
```

Это тоже самое, что написать:

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #8cffa0;
  padding: 10px;
}

#container>div {
  background-color: #8ca0ff;
  padding: 5px;
}

#container>div:nth-child(1),
#container>div:nth-child(2) {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    Элемент с дополнительным текстом. Поскольку его содержимое превышает максимальную ширину, оно ограничено 300 пикселей.
  </div>
  <div>
    Элемент с дополнительным текстом. Поскольку его содержимое превышает максимальную ширину, оно ограничено 300 пикселей.
  </div>
  <div>Флексовый элемент</div>
</div>
```

т.е. `fit-content` в гридах это ограничение максимального размера(не просто ширины или высоты).
В прошлых примерах был пример с рядами, вот с колонками:

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: fit-content(50px) fit-content(50px) 100px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #8cffa0;
  padding: 10px;
}

#container>div {
  background-color: #8ca0ff;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    lorem lorem lorem
  </div>
  <div>
    lorem lorem lorem
  </div>
  <div>Флексовый элемент</div>
</div>
```

Максимальная высота 1 и 2 элемента ограничена, но она очень маленькая, поэтому занимает свою исходную высоту

Comment: Получается, что если доступная ширина "под действием fit-content" > max-width →  max-width; доступная ширина "под действием fit-content" < min-width → min-width. Если употребляется только fit-content, то элемент "обрезает" лишнее пространство, отдавая тем самым предпочтение внутреннему контенту

Comment: @Eva а зачем вам это для просто width? Всё отлично адаптивно верстается, используя max-width/min-width